# Docker Engine version upgrade on Docker Swarm managed nodes, without downtime

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'd like to upgrade the Docker engine on my Docker Swarm managed nodes (both manager and worker nodes) from `18.06` to `19.03`, without causing any downtime.
I see there are many tutorials online for rolling update of a Dockerized application without downtime, but nothing related to upgrading the Docker engine on all Docker Swarm managed nodes.

Is it really not possible to upgrade the Docker daemon on Docker Swarm managed nodes without a downtime? If true, that would indeed be a pity.

Thanks in advance to the wonderful community at SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade managers, in place, one at a time. During this upgrade process, you would drain the node with `docker node update`, and run the upgrade to the docker engine with the normal OS commands, and then return the node to active. What will not work is to add or remove nodes to the cluster while the managers have mixed versions. This means you cannot completely replace nodes with an install from scratch at the same time you upgrade the versions. All managers need to be the same version (upgraded) and then you can look at rebuilding/replacing the hosts. What I've seen in the past is that nodes do not fully join the manager quorum, and after losing enough managers you eventually lose quorum.

Once all managers are upgraded, then you can upgrade the workers, either with in place upgrades or replacing the nodes. Until the workers have all been upgraded, do not use any new features.

Answer (score 0):

You can drain your node and after that upgrade your docker version,then make this ACTIVE again.
Repeat this step for all the nodes.

DRAIN availability prevents a node from receiving new tasks from the swarm manager. Manager stops tasks running on the node and launches replica tasks on a node with ACTIVE availability.

For detailed information you can refer this link :- https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/drain-node/

Comment: thanks @munish for your quick reply. I'm ready to try this but my senior colleague is worried this will not work since as per him swarm cannot manage nodes running different versions of docker engine. Do you know if this is a valid concern?

Comment: @mkumar118 we have done swarm upgrade by following above steps. but since you are running this on production. I will recommend you to first test this on some test swarm cluster and then apply this on the production setup, as a single mistake can be disastrous in your case. While doing this make sure that cluster quorum is always maintained.